# simulation alert box prevent all key by jquery

Tags: jquery

e.preventDefault and return false is not work, because that is prevent itself, and I wanna prevent all key especially Tab key when my alert box show.

I can set tabindex = -1 into input to prevent tab work for input, but tab still work for url bar.

but it does not work in default alert box include to tab to url bar. I mean cannot switch to url bar by Tab key when default alert show.

so how to do it? prevent all key. thank you.

Comment: an alert() stops js output. so i think there is no way to prevent it with js.do you have some snippets for us, so we can see, what ure doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
   return false;
});
```

and to make it stop:

```
$(window).off('keydown');
```

Comment: return false is deprecated. please use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Mephiztopheles - `event.returnValue = false` is deprecated. `return false` requires the dev understanding what the heck is happening when it's called ;D